# How do I determine sample size when the conversion rate for the null hypothesis is not deterministic?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, inference

I use a ML model to rank prospects in terms of purchase probability to send marketing emails on a monthly basis. Most of the people in the population (for example, the entire U.S population) would not be interested in the product. So when I send 5 millions of Emails in one month, the conversion rate is low say 0.005%. But when I send only 500k emails next month due to a suddenly very limited budget, the conversion rate could be 0.02%. If I want to test a new ranking model against the existing one, how would I decide the baseline conversion rate? I wonder if there is any theoretical discussion on this sort of problem.